# Javascript Unwanted Data Type Switching

Tags: javascript, variables

I have set a number variable under `c`. After running it through local storage  and a couple functions, the variable has turned into a string. Instead of `x` adding to `c` , `x` adds a digit to c. Can anyone see the problem?

```
function hi() {
    c += x;
    document.getElementById("paragraph").textContent = "This is a string" + c;
    localStorage.clocal = c;
}

function resetvar() {
    c = localStorage.clocal;
}

function bla() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("clocal") === "null") {
        document.getElementById("parargraph").textContent = "This Works Okay";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("parargraph").textContent = "This is a string" + localStorage.credits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data put in localStorage always as string.

If you wanna to get as number that you have to parse it

like this

```
c = parseInt(localStorage.clocal);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the nature of JS. You can use parseInt(c, 10) + x or x + 1 * c to over come this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit difficult to follow the flow of these methods, but one glaring issue I see is this line:

```
c += x
```

In this situation, you're saying that you want to set c equal to the result of c + x where x is a string, instead of setting x equal to x + c? By making this assignment, you are converting c to a string. Then after that point is doesn't matter what else you do -- it will still be a string unless you re-assign it explicitly as an integer.

I hope I understand your intention correctly.. It is a bit unclear.